# Picking large video files react native expo image picker

Tags: react-native, video, file-upload, expo, imagepicker

Trying to pick a video file to upload to mux from react native expo image picker.

Has no problem picking videos of 75mb getting this response after a few seconds:

`{uri: 'data:video/pm4;base64.AAAHDSHG...e.c.t', width: 0, height: 0, cancelled: false}`

However when I try to pick a video file >1gb after 30 seconds or so I don't get any error message just success with empty uri e.g.

`{uri: '', width: 0, height: 0, cancelled: false}`

Has it got something to do with the size of base64?

How do I pick a large video file to send to a server with react native expo ? Many thanks in advance

E.g. Code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

function CreateOnDemand(props) {

    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

    const pickImage = async () => {
        // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
          allowsEditing: true,
        //   aspect: [4, 3],
          quality: 0.9,
          base64: true,
        });
    
        console.log("result ", result);
    
        if (!result.cancelled) {
            console.log("Success! ", result)

          setImage(result.uri);
        } else {
            console.log("Failed ", result)
        }
    };


    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.contents}>
            <Button  onPress={pickImage}>
                Pick an image from camera roll
            </Button>
        </View>
    </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
        alignItems: 'center', 
    },
    contents: {
        maxWidth: 600,
        width: "100%",
    },
})


const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
    currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CreateOnDemand);
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "expo": "^44.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-av": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-cli": "^4.13.0",
    "expo-firebase-analytics": "~6.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
    "expo-image-picker": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-linking": "~3.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.1.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.6",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.7",
    "react-native-countdown-circle-timer": "^2.5.4",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.7.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.15.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you upload a video or an image, `expo-image-picker` fetch that video and save a copy to your app cache.

Depending on free memory available, over 1GB is the huge size on the device and there's no memory available to allocate that file copy.

Always limiting video size for upload is recommended.

It recommended clearing the app cache after successfully file upload.

```js
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";

const purgeAppCache = async () => {
  try {
    const cacheDirectory = FileSystem.cacheDirectory;

    await FileSystem.deleteAsync(cacheDirectory);

    console.log("app cache purged...");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export default purgeAppCache;
```

Comment: thanks for your help, it's a requirement for the app to be able to load large video files 1gb+ do you know of any alternative approaches?

Comment: Try to  calculate device available memory, In case it's less than 1GB, Recommend user to free up memory before attempting to upload a large file

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel I am currently struggling with a huge usage of the local storage (android and iOS). It seems like its caused by the video upload function in my app. Could the expo-image-picker library be the reason for that? Is there any way to release the used app cache?

Comment: Every time you upload new video or image  expo-image-picker generate copy of that file. You need to clear cached image after successfully upload

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel Thanks a lot for your quick response. Do you have any recommendation how to clear the video cache?

Comment: @F.Fabian check solution update

Comment: @FistonEmmanuel Your solution works perfectly on Android. Thanks a lot! Unfortunately on iOS I get this error: [Error: File 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4E5DAAB2-84D9-43BD-AE73-F77A18290BD0/Library/Caches/' could not be deleted.]

Comment: There'r possibilitities that that file is already used by other app or services. That's why not deleted but other file will be deleted